# What is known about the space of geodesic vector fields on a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a compact two-dimensional manifold. I'm interested in geodesic vector fields on $M$: smooth vector fields $v$ that have the property that every integral curve of the vector field is (locally) a geodesic. In other words
$$\nabla_v v = \phi v$$
where $\phi$ is a function $M\to\mathbb{R}$.

What is known about the space of such vector fields? Is there a way to characterize or parameterize them?

For example, I imagine one possible construction is to pick a closed subset $S$ of $M$, construct the signed distance function $d_S$ to $S$, and set $v = \nabla d_S$. This vector field is undefined at the cut locus of $S$, but presumably that can be fixed by adjusting the magnitude of $v$ so that it vanishes near the cut locus.

Comment: Isn't it $\nabla_v v = 0$ for geodesic?

Comment: @eranreches for unit speed geodesics yes, but I do not want to force the geodesics to be unit speed (so that $v$ can vanish at singularities)